# StreamWriting RichTextBox to .txt, no line breaks

Tags: c#, richtextbox

I'm trying to write a `RichTextBox`s content into a `.txt` file.
Line breaks in the `RichTextBox` do not appear in the `.txt`, they're simply ignored.

This is a screenshot of the problem:

[image: RTB Input + .TXT Output screenshot]

And this is the code I'm referring to:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(File.Open(String.Concat(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"\", "afa", @".txt"), FileMode.Create), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250")))
    {
        sw.WriteLine(this.textbox1.Text);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid I need the windows-1250 encoding, @LarsTech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [File class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file(v=vs.110).aspx) gives you [WriteAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383693(v=vs.110).aspx), or in your case, [WriteAllBytes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx) (For encoding) which will keep the line breaks intact. And you won't need to use StreamWriter either..

```
Encoding win1250 = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1250");
byte[] bytes = win1250.GetBytes(textBox1.Text);
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\TestFile.txt", bytes);
```

Comment: What about the windows-1250 encoding? The file needs to be encoded as such, any other options won't do.

Comment: Edited to add encoding.